# Who Defines Symbol \$MySource

Tags: notebooks, built-in-symbols

When I start up a fresh executing Mathematica on my MacOS system and I open a Notebook file there is always one symbol defined in the Global context.  This symbol is \$MySource and it points (via a directory symbolic link) to my default location for various notebook and package files.

I don't remember setting this up but I must have since it points to an iCloud folder that I myself created.  I have searched all preferences and other locations such as account defined environment variables and I can't find this definition anywhere.  I have searched the documentation for \$MySource and MySource but it leads to various content entries and none of those seem to contain the strings \$MySource or MySource.

If I change it to something different then when I shutdown Mathematica and start it up again it returns to the original definition to thru the directory link.

How do you set this value and does it have any special purpose other than providing a default file lookup location?

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using? Did you check if this was defined in `init.m`?

Comment: @J.M. Mathematica version 12.1 and init.m does not contain any references to `$MySource` or `MySource`.  Yes, I looked there.

Comment: @J.M. OK, I looked again.  After I posted the previous comment I decided that maybe there was more than one init.m file on my system.  I searched via shell find command and found more than a dozen `init.m` files.  Apparently, I looked in the wrong spot, the first hit from Mac OS Finder.  I found the definition of `$MySource` in the main default `init.m`.  However, I do not remember ever doing that definition.  Then again, I am 72+ in age so maybe I need to start writing stuff down.

Comment: @K7PEH where is the `init.m` file located where you have defined `$MySource`?

Comment: @CATrevillian It is located in the my user account Library folder (MacOS system).  Full path is:  /Users/peh/Library/Mathematica/Kernel/init.m.

Comment: Do you know "Pettson and Findus"? A repeating form of dialog goes like this (translated from the German version): Pettson: "Findus, why did you write that into my `init.m`?" Findus: "But Pettson, I didn't." Pettson: "Well, then I must have done it myself..."  Just as a side note: Findus is a cat. ;)

Comment: If commenting out or removing the offending line from `init.m` solved your problem, could you write this up in an answer to your question?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties  Are you talking to me?   If so, your very first comment answered my question.  I was looking for locations or methods of how this symbol had been defined and you pointed me to the right location.  However, it was never my intent to "comment out" or "remove" the definition of $MySource becasue I did not find it to be "offensive".  I was merely trying to figure out how or where it had been defined as I had no memory of doing it myself.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to get rid of it. My mistake. Still, it seems like it's worth writing up an answer to your question for reference.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties  I was thinking just the opposite -- the opposite being one of two alternatives: (1) since you answered my question via a comment, you could post an official answer; or, (2) delete the question since it seems to be very specific to a mystery that I personally had about these things.  With regard to alternative (2), after you brought up init.m I decided to search and read a number of the questions posted about init.m so I feel that an answer bringing up the utility of init.m would itself seem to be redundant or a duplicate.